# Best way to process set variables in batch files

Tags: variables, batch-file

This question is probably unnecessary as I probably have been searching for the wrong criteria. It's pretty easy I think but I just can't find the answer. I use batch files to automate installs with my work, setting folder permissions, copying files here, and there, silently running programs, removing old ones etc. The batch files contain lots of repetition and I want to tidy them up greatly for easier management. I have decided to set the repeated commands and copy folder locations as variables then use them instead. This is all fine but I'm adding the variables as a LIST which looks rubbish to me, I'm sure I can load them together in a sentence rather than a new line for each. Here's what I mean...

```
set dir1=md c:\newfolder
set killtask=taskkill /im someprog.exe /f >nul 2>&1
set config=echo F| XCOPY %~dp0configfile3.cfg /y C:\newfolder
```

And on and on...

So at the minute my batch now looks like this

---

### JOB1

```
%dir1%
%killtask%
%config%
```

What I want to be able to do is have it like this (to reduce length if batch file etc.)

---

### JOB1

```
%dir1% %killtask% %config%
```

Comment: I don't think, that your first JOB1 is able to run as expected. Check your variables! Use this syntax to correct it: `set "killtask=taskkill /im someprog.exe /f >nul 2>&1"` (note the quotes and their position)

Comment: Good call I did a trial run and it tried running a lot of the commands as it set everything ...now I know why. Thanks. Do you think it will run like I want now...as a sentence rather than a new line for each variable......

Comment: you can call several commands with `&`: `echo hello&echo world`. With your complex variables this would probably fail/work in an unexpected way. Try `(%dir1%)&(%killtask%)&(%config%), so that the redirections and pipes stay at their intended commands.

Comment: Fantastic! Real quick do I need these things`(%dir1%)&(%killtask%)&(%config%),

Comment: Just tested quickly and looks like a winner!  thanks a lot.  Previous was asking if I needed ' and ,  at the start and end of the  brackets but seems okay without.  Cheers!

Comment: sorry, the  ` is part of code-formatting in the comments. It somehow missed the second one. (text enclosed in those "rabbit ears"  are written in grey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(summary of my comments to the question):

Check your variables! Some chars like pipe (`|`) or redirection (`>`) change how the line is interpreted. Use this syntax to correct it:

```
set "killtask=taskkill /im someprog.exe /f >nul 2>&1"
```

(note the quotes and their position)

you can call several commands with `&`:

```
echo hello&echo world.
```

With your complex variables this would probably fail/work in an unexpected way. Try

```
(%dir1%)&(%killtask%)&(%config%)
```

so that the redirections and pipes stay at their intended commands.

Comment: just had a go with the real batch, my previous was basic ehco and new folder test, i was able to get it to work only by "removing" the brackets from all the variables?? thanks